# Ruby variable assigned false but is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The assignment statement looks like this:

```
my_var = false
```

And breaking on the *very next line*, the debugger shows 'my_var' with Type=NilClass and value=nil! How is this possible?

Comment: an awesome explanation of the problem.

Comment: Have you examined `my_var` without the debugger?

Comment: @mu is too short, this was it, the debugger was pegging it as nil but `my_var.class.to_s` showed FalseClass! Thank you, if you add this as an answer i'll accept it, otherwise i'll answer myself.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer for you. Never trust a debugger (or any other piece of software :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you examined `my_var` directly without any debugger? The debugger could be getting confused or just displaying confusing results.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the target object of your section of code has a "setter method" defined, so it looks like you're assigning to "my_var" but are actually calling the "`my_var=`" method.  See if your code has any definitions like this:

```
def my_var=(x)
  # ...
end
```

If so, you'll need to change the name of the local "my_var" variable or the setter method.  You could also verify by stepping into the line where you call "`my_var = false`".

Comment: `my_var = false` will never call a method - it's always a local variable assignment. To call a setter method, you need a receiver (e.g. `self.my_var = false`

Answer (score 1):

I found this very helpful [True, False and Nil](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/).